# Equivalent to HttpResponse.StatusDescription in .NET Core to set status code description

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

How do you change the status description from a .NET Core application? I am looking for something equivalent to the .NET 4.8 [HttpResponse.StatusDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.statusdescription?view=netframework-4.8).

Instead of

`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

I want to change Bad Request to something from my application

`HTTP/1.1 400 Custom Error Message`

I know there are other ways of sending error text. However, I need to support a legacy application that only reads the error message from the status code text field.

If relevant, this will be running on IIS using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/395

Comment: @Herohtar your link solved the problem. Are you going to make that an answer (instead of a comment)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach:

```
public class CustomResult : IActionResult
{
    private readonly string _errorMessage;
    private readonly int _statusCode;

    public CustomResult(string errorMessage, int statusCode)
    {
        _errorMessage = errorMessage;
        _statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var objectResult = new ObjectResult(_errorMessage)
        {
            StatusCode = _statusCode
        };

        await objectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

and usage in action filter:

```
context.Result = new CustomResult("Custom Error Message", StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
```

or in action itself:

```
public IActionResult Save()
{
    return new CustomResult("Custom Error Message", StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not sure whether you can use or not this in .Net Core 3.1 but I think it'll work:

```
return BadRequest(new ProblemDetails {Title = "Custom Error Message"});
```

Note: I use this code in .Net Core 2.2